# API gateway with lambda proxy throwing InternalServerError

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have a simple lambda that I am fronting through API gateway with Lambda proxy integration.

Here is my lambda code

```
exports.handler = main;

function main(event, context, callback) {
    console.log("This will get s3 files")
    //return "Succeed"
    var responseText = {
      message : "Succeeded"
    }
    return done(200, JSON.stringify(responseText), 'application/json', callback)
}

function done(statusCode, body, contentType, lambdaCallback, isBase64Encoded = false) {
  lambdaCallback(null, {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    isBase64Encoded: isBase64Encoded,
    body: body,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': contentType
    }
  });
}
```

When hitting with API Gateway, it throws internal server error. The api gateway logs in cloudwatch look like-

Endpoint response body before transformations: [Binary Data]
Endpoint response headers: {X-Amz-Executed-Version=2, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=8d332243-7b3d-11e8-afe1-c936514725a3, Content-Length=120, Date=Fri, 29 Jun 2018 01:41:32 GMT, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5b358e4c-623f1d6069f1dc0c3c25dda4;sampled=0, Content-Type=application/json}
Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to base64 decode the body.

If I invoke the lambda through console test, I get the correct response-

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Succeeded\"}",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}
```

Comment: I lifted the codes you posted here and created a lambda with api integration and it worked as expected. I could not recreate the issue you are having. Could you try to create a new lambda and copy paste your codes from your post and try it again?

Comment: After some playing around, I was able to replicate this, but only by removing the lambda proxy integration. Can you double check that you have ticked the 'Use Lambda Proxy integration' box in API Gateway integration request.